# Calculate the probability that the sample average of the second sample population exceeds the sample mean of the first sample by 3 units or more.

Tags: probability

A normal population has mean 3 and variance 4. A second normal population has mean.
5 and variance 6. Random samples are taken from both size 40 and 36 stocks.
respectively. Calculate the probability that the sample average of the second sample
population exceeds the sample mean of the first sample by 3 units or more.
population.

**My attempt:**

I think i need find $P(\bar{x}\leq 3\bar{y})$

I know $\bar{x}-\bar{y}\sim N(u_x+u_y,\frac{\sigma_x^2}{n_x-1}+\frac{\sigma_y^2}{n_y-1})$ but here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find $P(\overline{y}\geq\overline{x}+3)$, i.e. $P(\overline{y}-\overline{x}\geq 3)$.  We have $\mathbb{E}(\overline{Y}-\overline{X})=\mathbb{E}(\overline{Y})-\mathbb{E}(\overline{X})=5-3=2$. Assuming independence, we also have $\text{Var}(\overline{Y}-\overline{X})=\text{Var}(\overline{Y})+\text{Var}(\overline{X})=6/36+4/40=4/15$.  Plug "normalcdf(3,1E99,2,$\sqrt{4/15}$)" into your calculator to get the answer.